# How to save data in rails in oracle db without id column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I have a table `DIM_STORE` with columns `STORE_ID`, `STORE_NAME`, `CLIENT_CODE`, `CREATE_TIMESTAMP`, `UPDATE_TIMESTAMP`.

How to save a new record to oracle db in rails? `STORE_ID`, `STORE_NAME` and `CLIENT_CODE` are of `varchar` type. And I have a form through which I need to add a new store.

I am getting error as,

```
NoMethodError: undefined method \`returning_id?' for nil:NilClass: INSERT INTO "DIM_STORE" ("STORE_NAME", "STORE_ID", "CLIENT_CODE", "STORE_ID") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4)))
```

stores_controller.rb,

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new {|c| c.request.format == 'application/json'}
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :is_admin
  before_action :get_client
  before_action :set_store, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /stores
  # GET /stores.json
  def index
       @stores = Store.where("CLIENT_CODE = ?", @client.client_code)
    respond_to do |format|
      if request.format == :json
        format.json { render json: @stores.all}
      else
        format.js
        format.html
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /stores/1
  # GET /stores/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /stores/new
  def new
    respond_to do |format|
      @store = Store.new
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end

  def form

  end

  def new_store

  end

  # GET /stores/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /stores
  # POST /stores.json
  def create
    @store = Store.new(store_params)
    @store.client_code = @client.client_code
    puts @store
    respond_to do |format|
      if @store.save
        format.js
      else
        format.js {render "stores/new"}
        format.json {render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  #GET /stores/create_success
  def create_success
    redirect_to request.referrer, notice: 'Store was successfully created under client.'
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /stores/1
  # PATCH/PUT /stores/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @store.update(store_params)
        format.js
      else
        format.js {render 'stores/edit'}
        format.json {render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  #GET /stores/update_success
  def update_success
    redirect_to request.referrer, notice: 'Store was successfully updated.'
  end

  # DELETE /stores/1
  # DELETE /stores/1.json
  def destroy
    stores_users = @store.users
    if stores_users.nil? || stores_users.empty?
      @store.destroy
      redirect_to request.referrer, notice: 'Store was successfully destroyed.'
    else
      redirect_to request.referrer, notice: 'Users still associated with store. Cannot delete store'
    end
  end

  def get_client
    @client = Client.friendly.find(params[:client_id])
    puts @client.client_code
=begin
    @client = Client.find_by_sql ["SELECT * FROM DIM_CLIENT WHERE client_code = ? ", params[:client_id]]
    puts @client;
    @client.each do |c|
      @client_code = c[:client_code]
      @client_name = c[:client_name]
    end
    puts @client_code
=end
=begin
    @client.each do |c|
      puts c[:client_code];
    end
=end
=begin
    @client = Client.find_by_sql ["SELECT client_code FROM DIM_CLIENT WHERE client_code = ? ", :client_code]
=end
  end

  private
    def set_store
=begin
      @store = Store.find_by_sql ["SELECT store_id FROM DIM_STORE WHERE store_id = ? ", params[:id]]
=end
    @store = Store.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def store_params
      params.require(:store).permit(:store_name, :store_id, :client_code)
    end
end
```

Comment: What is the output in your `create` action here `puts @store` ? Also could you put debugger just before save and check `@store.valid?` and `@store.errors` ?

Comment: @store.valid? is returning me true.puts @store is an array object